# Velocity Model Motion in Matlab (Probabilistic Robotics)

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics, motion, motion-planning, noise

I want to implement the velocity motion model in Matlab. According to [Probabilistic Robotics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262201623) page 124, the model is as following

\begin{align*}
\hat{v}      &= v + sample(\alpha_{1} v^{2} + \alpha_{2} w^{2}) \\
\hat{w}      &= w + sample(\alpha_{3} v^{2} + \alpha_{4} w^{2}) \\
\hat{\gamma} &= sample(\alpha_{5} v^{2} + \alpha_{6} w^{2}) \\
x' &= x - \frac{\hat{v}}{\hat{w}} sin \theta + \frac{\hat{v}}{\hat{w}} sin(\theta + \hat{w} \Delta{t}) \\
y' &= y + \frac{\hat{v}}{\hat{w}} cos \theta - \frac{\hat{v}}{\hat{w}} cos(\theta + \hat{w} \Delta{t}) \\
\theta' &= \theta + \hat{w} \Delta{t} + \hat{\gamma} \Delta{t}
\end{align*}

where $sample(b^{2}) \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, b^{2})$. With this kind of variance $\alpha_{1} v^{2} + \alpha_{2} w^{2}$, the Kalman Gain is approaching singularity. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several traps you might have stepped into, but it is difficult to tell without more information. The first issues that came to my mind:

- The equations you wrote down are for *sampling* from the velocity motion model. But then you write about the Kalman Gain approaching singularity, which only makes sense of you apply a Gaussian filter (EKF or UKF). There is no sampling in EKF or UKF.
- The model above is not defined for $\omega = 0$. You need to handle this special case by computing the limit for $\omega \to 0$. Hint: [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)
- The model assumes perfect accuracy (no noise) if $\omega = v = 0$. This is a rather strong assumption and may or may not lead to problems.